# Vue: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title') on page reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a pretty common issue accessing data while the page is loading, however, I cannot figure this out.

My code is as follows:

```
    computed: {

       nowPlaying() {
               if(this.$store.state.radio && !this.loading) {
            
        let meta = Object.values(this.apollo).filter(el => el.channel === this.activeChannel)
          this.title = meta[0].title,
          this.artist = meta[0].artist
            }  
        },
```

Hot reload works as expected but page reload returns an undefined error for both title & artist:

*TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
at VueComponent.nowPlaying (Player.vue?7cf3:45:1)*

This happens only if I try to access an element in the meta array using [].

Comment: Can't exactly tell since it's only a small snippet, but it's certain that at one point your meta array ends up being empty and both the `state.radio` and `!this.loading` evaluate to true. 
Is it possible that your loading flag starts of as false and your state.radio has a truthy value before any data is present? 
Add a debugger or breakpoints to check the state of your app.

Comment: `meta` is an empty array and you're trying to access the first element of it, which is `undefined`. Can you do some debugging to figure out why this is? You need to write more defensive code and check first that the array isn't empty. Maybe you're not waiting for the initial data to load on page load before accessing `nowPlaying`?

Comment: @Mads I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like on page load, `this.apollo` or `this.activeChannel` not available as `computed` property always call prior to `mounted()` hook.

Can you please ensure that `this.apollo` and `this.activeChannel` is available in `mounted()` or data property.

Demo how it works **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      property: 'Example property'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    propertyComputed() {
      console.log('computed'); // Called first on page load
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>{{ propertyComputed }}</div>
</div>
```